# Where can I get Twitter access Token for python app?

Tags: python, api, twitter

Please take a look at the python code first.

```
import tweepy

# necessary keys for authorisation 
API_KEY = 'your_api_key'
API_SECRET = 'your_api_secret'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'your_access_token'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = 'your_access_token_secret'

# API authorisation 
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

# get tweets by keywords 
api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweets = api.search(q=['Python'], count=10)

for tweet in tweets:
    print('-----------------')
    print(tweet.text)
```

I wanted to make the coed above work, but after I requested an API on https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps/ they only gave me API Key, API Key secret and Bearer Token.
Where are  ACCESS_TOKEN and ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET?
As you can see in the picture below there was no ACCESS_TOKEN and ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET

[image]

Please let me know how I can solve it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link lower on the page where you can see your API tokens it should allow you to generate Access tokens as well

https://developer.twitter.com/ja/docs/basics/authentication/guides/access-tokens